# Caching a function (in a singleton service) within a single request to the controller in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

For each call to the endpoint below, I have to fetch values for multiple keys from external services so I would like to cache the results of `getValue` but only within each request. `getValue` will be called multiple times for the same input multiple times within a request. The results for the same key will vary across multiple requests.

Simplified version of my code is provided below.

I tried using a `CacheManager` with `@Scope("prototype")` but its caching the values across requests.
I tried using `@RequestScope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)` but I get `Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread` and the application wouldn't run.
I'd prefer just creating an empty `HashMap` for each request and cache the values there myself but unsure how to handle that since `LogicService` is a singleton.

```java
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class LogicController {
  private final LogicService logicService;

  @PostMapping("/logic")
  public Map<String, String> getValues(
      @RequestBody LogicRequest logicRequest
  ) {
    return logicService.getValues();
  }  
}
```

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class LogicService {

  Map<String, String> getValues() {
    // call getValue hundreds of times to generate output 
    // with a lot of calls having the same input
  }

  // how do I cache the results of this function just within one API call to /logic?
  @Cacheable(cacheManager = "requestCacheManager", cacheNames = "values", key = "#key")
  String getValue(String key) {
    // expensive function
  }
}
```

```java
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheManagerConfiguration {
  @Bean
  @Scope("prototype")
  public CacheManager requestCacheManager() {
    return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager("values");
  }
}
```

Comment: Since the same key appears in the list, the map might be smaller than the list, right? So that for `[a, b, c, a]`, your `getValues(List)` function returns `[<a, aVal>,<b, bVal>,<c, cVal>]`, since `Map#put` will update on duplicate keys. I'm guessing you try to cache because you might call `getValue(String)` for the same key more than once. Is it correct?

Comment: sorry - I just updated the sample code to focus more on the problem. Yes, I am trying to cache because `getValue` will be called for the same key more than once.

Comment: Ok, if that's the case, couldn't you remove the duplicate keys before mapping? That way `getValue` will be called only once per unique key.

Comment: its more like this dummy code so can't eliminate duplicates like that
```java
Map.of(
  "key1", (getValue("k1") + getValue("k2") + getValue("k3")),
  "key2", (getValue("k2") + getValue("k1") + getValue("k3")),
  "key3", (getValue("k3") + getValue("k2") + getValue("k1"))
);
```

Comment: You should definitely add that to your question. I would expect that for every key, a single result is retrieved. I was hoping to help you solve this without a caching mechanism, but with those k's I no longer see how the relation works. Adding that (What are those k's and where do they come from) will also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Include the GUID generated in the Controller in the cache key.

```
  @PostMapping("/logic")
  public Map<String, String> getValues(
      @RequestBody LogicRequest logicRequest
  ) {
    String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    return logicService.getValues(uuid);
  } 




@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class LogicService {

  Map<String, String> getValues(String uuid) {
    // call getValue hundreds of times to generate output 
    // with a lot of calls having the same input
  }

  @Cacheable(cacheManager = "requestCacheManager", cacheNames = "values")
  String getValue(String uuid, String key) {
    // expensive function
  }
}
```

On a separate note, the @Cacheable mechanism will not work for your code in the question. The method getValue(String key) must be called from outside the LogicService because java needs to proxy the call.